# Django ORM query to get data from multiple tables

Tags: sql, django, django-orm

I need to retrieve data from multiple tables to display shop name, shop location, shop monthly sales volume(unit), monthly sales amount, and sales person name who take orders from the shop.
My sample table example below:

**Order**

```
id      total_price   added_by_id(employee id)   customer_id
1       42480         2                          1
2       74920         3                          2
3       21000         3                          2
4       42480         2                          1
```

**OrderItem**

```
order_id      unit
1             1
1             2
2             2
2             2
3             2
4             5
```

**Customer**

```
id    full_name      location  
1     Shop1          Example location1
2     Shop2          Example location2
```

**Employee**

```
id    full_name      
1     Employee Name1          
2     Employee Name2
```

**And the resultant table should be**

```
shop name    location     salesperson        sales volume   monthly sales
Shop1        location1    Employee Name1     8              43630
Shop2        location2    Employee Name2     6              95920
```

**My Try:**

```
Order.objects.select_related('account_customer').all()
.values('customer_id')
.annotate(total_sales=Sum('total_price'))
.filter(created_at__year=today.year, created_at__month=today.month)
```

It will return

```
<QuerySet [{'customer_id': 1, 'total_sales': Decimal('43630.00')}, {'customer_id': 2, 'total_sales': Decimal('95920.00')}]>
```

I can't retrieve other necessary information like shop name, location, salesperson name sales volume.

Related models:

```
class Order(models.Model):
    added_by = models.ForeignKey(Employee, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    total_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=18, decimal_places=2)

class OrderItem(models.Model):
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    unit = models.FloatField()

class Customer(models.Model):
    shop_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Employee(AbstractUser):
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

How can I retrieve all of my necessary information?

Comment: can you add your related models ?

Comment: added @JerinPeterGeorge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the required fields to `values()` as,

```
Order.objects.select_related('account_customer').all() \
    .values('customer_id', 'other_field_1', ...) \
    .annotate(total_sales=Sum('total_price')) \
    .filter(created_at__year=today.year, created_at__month=today.month)
```

This is equivalent to a **SQL GROUP BY** statement.
For more details read the [official django doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/aggregation/)

**UPDATE-1**

```
Order.objects.annotate(
    location=F('customer__address'),
    salesperson=F('added_by'),
    shop_name=F('customer__shop_name')
).values('shop_name', 'salesperson', 'location').annotate(sales_volume=Count('orderitem__unit'),
                                                          monthly_sales=Count('total_price'))
```

Comment: This query not return total volume. See my resultant table sales volume column

Comment: Your model fields and resultant table fields seem different. Please do correct it, or provide a sample SQL statement you wish to generate

Comment: My resultant table sales volume should calculate from OrderItem unit column. Is there any confusion to you.?

Comment: `location` and `sales volume` are confusing

Comment: Location are specified in customer model named as address and the unit column in orderitem model need to calculate based on order foreign key

Comment: oopps... Can you tell me , how that 8 and 6 comes in resultant table ?

Comment: See on order table cusyomer id column... Customer id 1 have order id of 1, 4 . Now look at order item table then sum unit by order id 1, 4, you will get 8. Understand?

Comment: Update 1 worked for me. Just change count to sum. Now its fine.